# Python встроить библиотеку в файл

Tags: python, библиотеки, адаптивность

Я создаю приложение на Python и задумался над одной проблемой. Python есть не на всех устройствах, а тем более модули которые я использую. Есть идеи как встроить интерпретатор и модули в .exe шник? Если я не ошибаюсь, minecraft сам при установке импортирует Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начну с конца, Minecraft не тянет JRE (Java Runtime Environment - она же Java-машина), из-за чего всего и возникала проблема у школьников (во всяком случае ещё лет 6 назад), где скачать и как устанавить эту непонятную для них Джаву.

По поводу того, как переносить настроенное окружение Python, тут как минимум 2 варианта.
Первый - в каталоге с файлом запуска держать папку с python'ом, где будут и подтянутые библиотеки и нужная версия интерпретатора. Для запуска можно создать .bat файл, в котором пропишете строку запуска приложения, или же можно для красоты создать или на том же c\c++ .exe файл, который будет иметь и иконку и расширение .exe
Второй - по сути усложнение первого варианта - использовать PyInstaller, он создаст вам сборку python проекта в .exe файл. Но на самом деле, это просто архиватор, при запуске этого exe'шника, это приложение распакует те же файлы во временную папку и оттуда будет тянуть.

Comment: То есть я могу просто когда выкладываю файл заархивировать его и в архив положить: само приложение, интерпретатор с установленными библиотеками?

Comment: @retr12, в целом да. Потом запускать командой по типу `./python/python.exe ./run.py`, соответственно, запустив свой экземпляр интерпретатора, он будем смотреть на свои локальные загруженные библиотеки, они в папке Lib находятся. При этом, для разработки каждого отдельного проекта на Python желательно создавать виртуальное окружение, чтобы не тянуть ненужные библиотеки из других проектов